# Do I need to null out an object reference in C# before the method ends?

Tags: c#, memory, collections, null, garbage

Im newer to C# and can't seem to find a direct answer to this:

So in a method I create an object reference to read an xml doc:

```
XElement xFinancialBill = xDoc.Root.Element("Financial_Transaction").Element("Bill");
```

It does some processing with the object and the method ends, but my question is: do I need to null out the above object reference (eg. `xFinancialBill = null;`) before the method ends for garbage collection/freeing up memory to work correctly?

Comment: No, the garbage collector will take care of it once the variable is out of scope and is not referenced anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you don't need to worry about object references once they have gone out of scope - the garbage collector will clear up.

However, if you are using an object whose class implements the `IDisposable` interface then you need to make sure that it disposes of any unmanaged resources by either explicitly calling the `IDisposable.Dispose()` method or by wrapping its usage in a `using` block.

Look up `IDisposable` in the MSDN for further explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

No. The garbage collector will free all objects that are not reachable any more and local variables of a method that has finished are in this category (provided you did not have additional references e.g. because you returned the value or stored it in a member field etc.